# How to convert typescript modules to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, tsconfig

I have a src working directory like this:

```
- src
  - functions
  - final
  - utils
```

I have **two** files, both inside "final" which I need to transpile from typescript to javascript to run in browser.

The thing is: my final files are importing functions and classes from the other src folders files, but when I transpile it into javascript, it does not work since the imported lines does not actually brings in the functions and classes

my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
"target": "es3",
"lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017", "ES2021"],
"module": "commonjs",
"rootDir": "./src", 
"outDir": "./dist",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
}
}
```

What can I do in order to have it transpiled with the modules to the javascript files I need??

Comment: You can use `es6` modules instead of `commonjs` if you want it to run on the web.

Comment: It just brings the function name but not its content

Comment: How are you transpiling your files? What command are running? What tool or bundler are you using?

Comment: I'm using typescript 4.6.4 ,the command is 'tsc'

Comment: use `files` options in tsconfig.json which is outside of `compilerOptions`. You can use like "files":["./src/functions/a.ts" , "./src/functions/b.ts" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tsc` only compiles files in place. It does not bundle.

To run your project in the browser, you typically need a bundler (such as  webpack, parcel, vite, or rollup) to compile and package your code for use in web browsers.

Comment: Is it possible to generate ES3 javascript code with Webpack through Typescript files?

Comment: What do you mean "through typescript files"?

Comment: I mean, webpack can also convert typescript to javascript ES3 in its configuration?

Comment: Yes: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/